# How to debug the API Action process_mailing?

Tags: scheduled-job

Drupal Version:7.59
CiviCRM Version:5.3.1
I am facing an error of incorrect Links in Emails sent via scheduled mailings.

The HTML is

```
<a href="https://example.com/sites/example2.com/files/abc.pdf">Test</a>
```

1) When mail is sent manually by selecting **Execute Now**
[image]

the links for the pdf works perfectly

2) When it runs via cron 
the link generated is this
/usr/share/nginx/abc/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=2937&qid=34399

I need to debug on both #1 and #2, what can be the appropriate files to debug and what can be the process to debug?

I am having a **symlink** so in 

Settings - Upload Directories

[cms.root]  
/usr/share/nginx/abc

[civicrm.root]
  /usr/share/nginx/abc/sites/all/modules/civicrm

[civicrm.files]
 /usr/share/nginx/abc/sites/default/files/civicrm

Resource URL 

[cms.root]  
https://example.com/
[civicrm.root]  
https://example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/
[civicrm.files]
    https://example.com/sites/example2.com/files/civicrm/

Comment: It appears as though you have link tracking enabled for your mailing - that's the general format that tracked links follow (except of course for being a relative link and not absolute).  Are you using Mosaico by chance?  Are you using any kind of third party sending tool (e.g., SendGrid, Sparkpost)?

Answer (score 2):

Harshal,

Check the resource url is set properly. Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URLS. Click on '?' to see if all the variables have correct values and are pointing to right directories. If not then you may need to update the civicrm.settings.php file for $civicrm_root variable until the you get th variables right in resource url.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi I am using a symlink , can that be an issue, apart from that , I dont see the resource url to be havng any issue, i have updated my question,kindly have a look at and provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: I am taking about RESOURCE URL not the directory path. Yes sometimes symlink is problem. Is you resource url have correct path?

Comment: how can I debug and find the issue ?

Comment: can you add the resource url variables into your post?

Comment: Hi i have added resource url variables, kindly have a look at it

Comment: Looks good. Not sure why its doing that. Probably the url is not set during cron run. Which method are you using for cron?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83954/discussion-between-harshal-and-pradeep-nayak).